# CakePHP 2, CakePHP conditions, Dynamic condition on search, MySQL expression

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, conditional-statements

I am trying to build a search query for report in my CakePHP application. In my query condition building go through a if, else statements. On initial load of report I want to load the pre-defined criteria and when user submit the search conditions will be changed on selection.

This is my initial conditions

```
$conditions['Report.expense_status'] = array('COMPLETED');
$conditions['DATE(Report.created) >='] = "date_sub(now(), interval 2 month)";
```

When user do a search conditions should update as below.

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {

    $search = $this->request->data('Report');
    if( strlen($search['From']) > 0 ){                
        $conditions['DATE(Report.created) >='] = date( 'Y-m-d',strtotime($search['From']) );
    }
}
```

But my initial condition code output the SQL expression as below and it is not getting populate the result.

```
DATE(`Report`.`created`) >= 'date_sub(now(), interval 2 month)'
```

it is adding quotes to the expression.

How should prevent adding quotes around condition?

Form:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Report', array('action' => 'index')); ?>
<div>
    <?php

    echo $this->Form->input('Keyword');
    echo $this->Form->input('Status',
                            array(
                                'options' => $status,
                                'multiple'=> 'false'
                            )  
                        );
    echo $this->Form->input('Child',
                            array(
                                'options' => $children,
                                'multiple'=> 'false'
                            )   
                        );
    echo $this->Form->input('From',
                            array(
                                'id' => 'report_from'
                            )
                        );
    echo $this->Form->input('To',
                            array(
                                'id' => 'report_to'
                            )
                        );
    ?>
    <div class="footer">
        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Search" name="action">
            <input type="button" value="Cancel" name="action">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

Comment: Add your view file code (form code). And why `strlen($search['From'])`?

Comment: strlen($search['From']) added to check if from date is available in search submit.

Comment: $conditions=array('Report.expense_status' => 'COMPLETED','DATE(Report.created) >=' => 'date_sub(now(), interval 2 month)');
is this method works?

Comment: It is adding quotes to query condition as I mentioned in question.
DATE(`Report`.`created`) >= 'date_sub(now(), interval 2 month)'
If I can remove the quotes in 'date_sub(now(), interval 2 month)' the query will be fine.

Comment: If you built $conditions array like that it won't quoted.

Comment: $conditions = array(
            'Report..expense_status' => array('COMPLETED'),
            'DATE(Report.created) >=' => 'date_sub(now(), interval 2 month)'
        );

This is what I am added and the same problem is happening.